# Match two comma separated numbers with period as decimal separator inside angle brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to build a regex pattern in C# for matching the following format

> `<0.0,100000.0>`

and so far came up with this regex

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"[<(]*[0-9][.]*[0-9][,]*[0-9][.]*[0-9][>)]$");
```

But this regex is accepting something like `<0,100000>`

Generally I want to match a range where numbers need to have a decimal separator.

**Edit**: Finally I used this

```
var regexItem = new Regex(@"^[(<]\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+[)>]$");
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Remove the `*` after the `[.]`s.  Also, you could just use `\.` rather than `[.]`

Comment: It's also not requiring the enclosing `<>` brackets.  And it's not requiring the `,` delimiter.  And it's only allowing single digit numbers.

Comment: It seems you just can use `@"<\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+>"`, or `@"<\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+>|\(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\)"` (to validate both numbers in angle and round brackets). In .NET, compile with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag to only match ASCII digits.

Comment: I used this
`@"[(<]\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+[)>]"` because range can starts with round with angle bracket

Comment: Post what you learned as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to simplify this regex to see the problem.

`[0-9]` is actually equal to `\d`. Also if `[]` only has one value inside it, the brackets can be omitted (as long as the item inside is escaped if required): Therefore `[.]` -> `\.`

```
[<(]*\d\.*\d,*\d\.*\d[>)]$
```

Now looking at this I think what has happened is that you have put the `*` before an element instead of after it. Also dots should also be escaped (because they actually mean any character, not a literal dot)

So this should hopefully do the trick:

```
^[<(]\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+[>)]$

var regexItem = new Regex(@"^[<(]\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+[>)]$");
```

You'll have to modify the regex yourself to match your exact needs, this merely fixes the problem that you specified in your question.

Comment: It will also find a match in [`$%^&HGFVHNJ(.,.>`](https://regex101.com/r/H2BlV9/1), thus, I am not sure how this expression "does the trick".

Comment: The statement _Also if [] only has one value inside it, the brackets can be omitted_ is incorrect as you latter show when you state that the periods will need to be escaped.

Comment: You may add ^ in front of your expression to match whole string from `BEGINNING`, not only from the `END`